# Data Preprocessing in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis

I wanted to know, what's wrong with that code because the null values didn't fill with the values which I gave it. I'm trying to fill nan with the mean of the DateTime of joined for each team.

````
df['Joined'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Joined'])
mean_joined_data = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Joined', index=['Club'], aggfunc=np.mean)
mean_joined_data = mean_joined_data.reset_index()

df['Joined'] = df.Joined.fillna(mean_joined_data.Joined, axis=0)
df['Joined'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Joined'])
df['Joined'].isnull().sum()```
````

Answer (score 0):

Not all nans are the same. math.isnan np.isnan and pd.isna are not equivalent. Is it possible your nans take on one of these forms?